# Is it possible to short-check part of my baggage in a connecting flight?

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, check-in

I'll be traveling from Rio de Janeiro (**GIG**) to Paris (**ORY**) with a connecting flight in Lisbon (**LIS**). All  flights are with **TAP** (Air Portugal) and there is a **3 hour** wait in Lisbon.

Is it possible to check part of my baggage to Paris and part to Lisbon?

I have friends living there that asked if I could bring them some of the stuff they left in Brazil. I would plan to leave that part of the baggage with them, with no need to re-check-in.

Comment: Could you simply bring those items in your carry-on ?

Comment: Some of the stuff is heavy and voluminous, so carrying it would be uncomfortable and inconvenient. On the other hand, I am allowed 2 bags and I only need one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking-in bags to different destinations when flying with a layover](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/checking-in-bags-to-different-destinations-when-flying-with-a-layover)

Comment: The "duplicate" is regarding an overnight layover, not a short connection. I agree there is useful information there

Comment: I really hope you REALLY trust your friends. This is one way people become unknowing mules. I’d instead suggest you’d help them mail it to themselves. Much less risk to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a related question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/can-i-pick-up-my-luggage-between-flights-with-the-same-company/22955#22955) however your situation is slightly different. You are looking to short-check one bag to Lisbon. As the related post says, airlines are often reluctant to do this as they wish to ensure that you are flying the itinerary as sold. People who request to short-check bags are sometimes attempting to take advantages of fare discrepencies to bypass the airline's revenue management, and many airlines have instituted policies to prevent it.

In your case, it is obvious that short-checking only one bag would not allow you to leave the airport at LIS. If the airline personnel are logical, they should understand this and tag only one bag to ORY and one to LIS. Technically, this is entirely possible.

Update: I contacted TAP and they said all you need to do is inform their staff at check-in.

Comment: Thank you! Now that I know what it is called, I could find better answers for my question. I think this article clears all the doubts, for now: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/checking-in-bags-to-different-destinations-when-flying-with-a-layover

Comment: @lpacheco Airlines are often willing to short-check with an overnight layover though. A 3 hour connection is a bit different to the one you link to

Comment: Nice, +1. I expected this to be more difficult. However with only 3 hours in LIS the OP should rather hurry and not be delayed, since they have to pass immigration, get the luggage, hand it to friends waiting at arrivals and pass security again. Or is there a way to have someone else pick up the luggage?

Comment: @mts 3 hours should be fine without any delay. Good point if there's a delay. The OP will have to abandon the luggage and somehow persuade the airport to allow the recipient to receive this. There must be a way to delegate luggage to someone

Comment: They'll have to pass immigration anyway since LIS is their first Schengen entry point. I'm not sure if LIS has transfer security normally, but they'll certainly have to exit the secure area with the bag, taking it through customs, and then go back around to the departures side to go through security and re-enter.

Comment: @ZachLipton That should solve the problem then. If the OP misses the connection, the airline will rebook anyway