# Retrieving checked bags from a connecting flight

Tags: transit, luggage, hidden-city-ticketing

On my way home from my honeymoon, we have a scheduled stop in Houston prior to flying home. If I were to get off and stay in Houston instead of flying home, how can I get my bags that are probably being transferred to the connecting flight and get a ride home instead of flying that night?

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/can-i-pick-up-my-luggage-between-flights-with-the-same-company/22955#22955

Comment: What is your itinerary?

Answer (score 4):

If your incoming flight is international, then you will have to reclaim your bags at Houston anyway. You can then just leave the airport.

Edit, as Doc says, this is providing you're not doing an international to international ([ITI](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/travel-tourism/george-bush-intercontinental-airport-iah)) transfer on certain airlines.

If not, your options are:

- Request that your bags are [short checked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14807/checking-in-bags-to-different-destinations-when-flying-with-a-layover/14813#14813) (as noted by Zach, this may be refused)
- Travel with hand luggage only
- Ship your bags, e.g. [UPS](https://www.theupsstore.com/pack-ship/travel-luggage)
- Change your ticket - Call your airline and ask how much to reprice your tickets. This is usually cheaper after taking the first flight.
- Travel to Houston and then inform airline you will not be taking the connecting flight and ask them to unload your bags
- Abandon your bags - Risky alternative. Since your final flight is a US domestic flight, your bags may just continue to your destination and you have the possibility of retrieving them later (if they don't go missing)

Comment: They may well refuse to short check the bag under this scenario assuming the layover is reasonably short (e.g. [Delta officially won't do it](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/delta-air-lines-skymiles/1678943-short-check-bags.html))

Comment: @ZachLipton True, but the linked article also mentions that. Somewhat...

Comment: Why do you say that "your final flight is a US domestic flight"? I could not find any mention of this in the post.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because the OP said they'd otherwise get a ride home from there. Guess they could be getting a ride to Mexico...

Comment: Note that if doing an international -> international connection in Houston it is NOT always required to collect bags.  This is unique to Houston (IAH) and only applies to certain airlines (mainly UA and partners)