# What does "SSCI" on my boarding pass mean?

Tags: tickets, airports, airport-security, singapore-airlines

I recently flew on Singapore Airlines from Sydney to Singapore, and my boarding pass had `SSCI` printed on it.  **What does this mean?** Is it in some way related to the dreaded [`SSSS`](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6383/what-does-ssss-on-my-boarding-pass-mean?rq=1) (selected for extra security screening) at US airports?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fortunately, the answer is rather mundane: it's short for **Self-service check-in**, meaning you've already checked in online but had a boarding pass reissued at the airport.

As far as I can tell this changes nothing about airport security etc, so I'm not entirely sure why this is worth recording on the boarding pass, but apparently somebody thought it was.

Comment: Gee, it's too bad that "SSSS" doesn't stand for "self-service security screening."

Comment: @phoog Would people be cavity-searching themselves? :)

Comment: I think that's allowed, but you're supposed to do it in a restroom stall.